# Application to track task progress with reporting

Tags: project-management, time-management, productivity, todo

I'm searching for an app that will allow me to keep track of my personal projects. I need to be able to split projects into tasks.

Reporting is really important:

1) I need to see my progress over week/month/year. For example, last month I moved from 20 to 70% in project XYZ and completed project ABC.

2) For each project/task I need to know how much time it took to complete (from the day it was added to completion date).

The app should be free to use (up to N projects for example).

The percentage completion can be set either manually or be based on estimated/real time spent on project, I'm flexible here. The main point is to see that project is going forward.

Comment: Please add more info. How are you going to calculate your percentages (i.e. put in estimates), by number of task or task duration? [And read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: You should also search this site for things like [simple project management](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+simple+project+management) or [estimate tasks](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+estimate+tasks). Your question is probably a duplicate of one of those, but since it misses requirements like OS/price we cannot point at an exact duplicate.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question and will also look at links you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

How about [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.weebly.com/)? I think it ticks all your boxes:

- create a project with as many sub tasks as you want,
- add a time estimate for how long each of the tasks/sub tasks will take,
- track your time you spend on your tasks in the app itself,
- there is no progress bar view to visualize task/subtask completion, but you can put a percentage of how far along your task is (if you divide your task into multiple subtasks, the percentage of their completion will be reflected in the overall percentage of the main task they belong to),
- in the Gantt Chart view, you can monitor your task progress (once you color your tasks) within a day, a week, a month, etc.
- it's a desktop software that runs on Windows, do if you are looking for a web app, that will not work for you,
- it is free and open source.

Maybe worth a look.

Comment: This link is not correct,